# gpg: keyserver receive failed: Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: gpg, ipv6

System: Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon, based on Ubuntu 18.04.

---

Upon my limited knowledge of `gpg`, which version I will state here for future references:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4
libgcrypt 1.8.1
```

I thought the following command does not need anything special specified:

```
$ gpg --recv-keys 402543B2D98854007F627D36A63A58A3F2E17569
```

But I get the following error upon executing it:

> ```
> gpg: keyserver receive failed: Address family not supported by protocol
> ```

Sometimes, it works as expected, so I am unsure how to proceed, I am unable to pinpoint the problem?

---

**Note, that I only have IPv4, no IPv6, if that is relevant.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cause

This error may happen when one is **not connected to IPv6 network**.

---

### Source

I have just installed GnuPG on my FreeBSD, and it kindly informed me, quoting:

> GnuPG, when run on hosts without IPv6 connectivity, may fail to connect to dual-stack hkp servers.

---

### Workaround on FreeBSD

Add this line:

```
disable-ipv6
```

to the file:

```
/usr/local/etc/dirmngr.conf
```

---

### Applied to Linux Mint 19

1. To make sure that new options are read and that after the installation of a new GnuPG version the installed `dirmngr` is running, you may want to kill an existing `dirmngr` first:

```bash
sudo gpgconf --kill dirmngr
```

2. Applied to my Linux Mint 19, there is no default location of this config file.

Various places are read, I will only note that I have successfully created the file in:

```
    ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf
```

3. In addition to answering the question, let me note, that should you encounter any further errors, add this to the config file too:

   ```
    debug-level guru
    log-file ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.log
   ```